# SQL insert, delete, update

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server-2012-express

So i see that SQL has some tables which hold the newly inserted and deleted data from tables one may refer. I didn't notice such a table for updated data. I am currently working with triggers and i need to apply a trigger to an update. How do i do that?

```
USE [examene]
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[trig1]    Script Date: 6/8/2013 6:48:26 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER trigger [dbo].[trig1] on [dbo].[participari]
after insert,update,delete
as
begin
    if (exists (select * from deleted))
        rollback

    if (exists (select * from inserted,proiecte
where inserted.idpr = proiecte.idpr
and deadline<dela union 
select * from inserted,proiecte
where inserted.idpr = proiecte.idpr and inserted.panala>proiecte.deadline))
        rollback
end
```

this is my trigger so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as `updated` virtual table. When update occurs old values might be found in `deleted` and new values in `inserted`

> **[Use the inserted and deleted Tables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx)**
> The deleted table stores copies of the affected rows during DELETE and
> **UPDATE** statements. During the execution of a DELETE or UPDATE
> statement, rows are deleted from the trigger table and transferred to
> the deleted table.
>
> The deleted table and the trigger table ordinarily
> have no rows in common. The inserted table stores copies of the
> affected rows during INSERT and **UPDATE** statements. During an insert or
> update transaction, new rows are added to both the inserted table and
> the trigger table. The rows in the inserted table are copies of the
> new rows in the trigger table.
>
> **An update transaction is similar to a delete operation** followed by an
> insert operation; the old rows are copied to the deleted table first,
> and then the new rows are copied to the trigger table and to the
> inserted table.

Comment: so basically all the update info is newly inserted after deleting the old entries?

Comment: @user1889231 That only means that from trigger's point of view it's a pair of delete and insert operations. Included next paragraph from docs.